# SignalR Multiple Groups

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, signalr

I am building a SignalR chat room, where a user can be in many different "Groups" at the same time.

My issue is, that if the user joins Groups, "A", "B" and "C" - they're actively connected to these groups.

And the other user joins Group "B". If this user then sends a message in the Kendo UI chat, the other user receives this same message in Groups, "A", "B" and "C" because this user is part of Group "B".

Has anyone come across this "issue" before?

Thanks